# CodeIgniter / Xinha ImageManager not uploading images

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using the Xinha text editor in a CodeIgniter project, and normally it works very well, but this has got me stumped.

When I click the ImageManager icon in the Xinha, it loads the dialog box as usual, and allows me to upload an image. Within the editor, it shows that my image is uploaded, yet when I look directly at the directory using FTP it isn't there. Also, as the image is being inserted with the text, the reference to the image appears, but the image itself doesn't.

The dialog box shows the correct directory, and (according to my web host) the security on the folders is correct. (It's a Linux based server, and the permissions on the folder are 755. I've been told not to use 777 and the files should upload ok anyway).

So, any ideas? There's no actual code to show, as it's done through the Xinha plugin, though I can copy the PHP config files if that'll help.

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with a different plugin (that shouldn't matter, the problem is that uploading is not working).

My problem was that my php.ini didn't even have a directory to put "temporary" uploads, which is how php can even handle them. Once I added that, everything worked fine for me.

Also, you say in the past this has worked for you, but has it worked with the same host? Maybe the server configuration is a little different?

Comment: Thanks Matthew.

It has worked for the same host. As for server configuration, I wouldn't put it past them to change something and not tell us.

Having said that, I've just tested it after a break and it seems to be ok now. I'm not sure why it didn't work earlier.